# Halide error loading png images using libpng in VS 2015 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2015, png, libpng, halide

When I tried to call `load_image` function in Halide, I got an error "error during init_io". Debugging shows the error is in `load_png` function.

```
bool load_png(const std::string &filename, ImageType *im) {
#ifdef HALIDE_NOPNG
    return false;
#else // HALIDE_NOPNG
png_byte header[8];
png_structp png_ptr;
png_infop info_ptr;

/* open file and test for it being a png */
Internal::FileOpener f(filename.c_str(), "rb");
if (!check(f.f != nullptr, "File %s could not be opened for reading\n", filename.c_str())) return false;
if (!check(fread(header, 1, 8, f.f) == 8, "File ended before end of header\n")) return false;
if (!check(!png_sig_cmp(header, 0, 8), "File %s is not recognized as a PNG file\n", filename.c_str())) return false;

/* initialize stuff */
png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (!check(png_ptr != nullptr, "png_create_read_struct failed\n")) return false;

info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
if (!check(info_ptr != nullptr, "png_create_info_struct failed\n")) return false;

**if (!check(!setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)), "Error during init_io\n")) return false;**

png_init_io(png_ptr, f.f);
png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
```

This is the caller function

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Halide.h"
#include "halide_image_io.h"
using namespace Halide::Tools;

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    Halide::Image<uint8_t> input = load_image("../images/rgb.png");

    save_image(input, "brighter.png");

    printf("Success\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Environment.

1. Visual Studio 2015
2. Libpng 1.2.35
3. zlib 1.2.11
4. Windows 7

I have tried this solution, but it doesn't help.
[libpng: writing a png fails: stops at header write error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061331/libpng-writing-a-png-fails-stops-at-header-write-error)

Any idea?

Comment: Is this in new code of yours, or is it failing in existing Halide tests/apps that already use this code? (e.g. tests/correctness/image_io.cpp)

Comment: @StevenJohnson As a Windows user, he probably got the latest binary release from 2016/10/22 vs. the Linux default of building from source. You guys should do more releases.

Comment: Can you upload the rgb.png file here?

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I used rgb.png from the halide tutorial folder.

Comment: @StevenJohnson I write my own test code. I will try to run image_io.cpp to see if everything is okay or not

Comment: 2016/10/22 -- ouch, yes, that's a long time ago. I'll bring it up.

Comment: Is it caused by the older release? I've checked /tests/correctness/image_io.cpp", it seems that the test is skipped for windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an issue using a pre-compiled DLL/ static library. I've managed to solve the issue by compiling the latest libpng from the source using VS 2015.